# One-sample t-test: Expressing our data as “percent of control”

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, anova, t-test

[**This website**](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-sample-t-test-in-r) says that in a control and treatment experiment:

*"if you express your data as `“percent of control”`, you can [use **one-sample t-test** to] test whether the average value of treatment condition differs significantly from $100$"*.

In `R`, suppose we have the following data for `control` and `treatment`, how can we demonstrate what that website means?

```
set.seed(0)
control <- rnorm(60, 0)
set.seed(0)
treatment <- rnorm(53, 1.5)
```

Comment: I would be reluctant to rely on the advice on that website.  In the present case there are multiple problems with this "percent of control" recommendation, as you can see by writing a probability model for the results. Presumably data are paired treatment and control observations, $(T,C),$ which may depart from hypothetical true values $(\tau,\gamma).$ Let $(X,Y)=(T,C)-(\tau,\gamma)$ be those departures and suppose they are independent. Then "percent of control" is $$100\frac{T}{C}=100\frac{\tau+X}{\gamma+Y}$$ is likely to have a skewed distribution not amenable to the Student t test.

Comment: The usual solution is the paired t test.  It is tantamount to testing the hypothesis $T-C=0.$

Comment: @whuber, Many thanks for your prompt reply. At some point if you felt like you wanted to expand on your comment or write a formal answer e.g., using `R`, I would be delighted to  accept and upvote (none of which you need:).